# Error “500 internal server error”, en una llamada Ajax (.NET)

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, .net, asp

Me aparece el error 500 Internal Server Error

Este es mi Web method

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string EliminarDocumento(int IdDocumento)
        {
            string mensaje = "";
            bool resultado = false;
            using (var db = new ContratosEntities())
            {
                using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var reg = db.Cat_FormatoLiberados.Find(IdDocumento);
                        reg.Activo = false;
                        reg.FechaModifico = DateTime.Now;
                        db.Entry(reg).CurrentValues.SetValues(reg);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        tran.Commit();
                        resultado = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        mensaje = ex.Message;
                        resultado = false;
                        tran.Rollback();
                    }
                }
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Mensaje = mensaje, Resultado = resultado });
        }
```

y mi funcion JS, el web method esta dentro de la carpeta Catalogos

```
function eliminarCampoAceptar() {
    var IdDocumento = $("#idToErase").val();
    if ($('#hdnIdContrato').val() == 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < nuevosCampos.length; i++) {
            if (idCampo == nuevosCampos[i].IdCampo) {
                nuevosCampos.splice(i, 1);
                i = nuevosCampos.length + 10;
            }
        }

        $('#tbl-Campos tbody tr#campo-' + idCampo).remove();
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../Catalogos/FormatosLiberados.aspx/EliminarDocumento',
            data: "{ 'IdDocumento': " + IdDocumento + " }",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response != null) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response.d);
                    if (data.Resultado) {
                        $('#tbl-Formatos tbody tr#campo-' + IdDocumento).remove();
                    }
                }
            },
            method: 'POST'
        });
    }
}
```

Ni siquiera llega a la funcion del web method al mandarla llamar
La url es correcta que puede faltar?

(Texto extra sin relevancia alguna porque no me deja publicar la pregunta
********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hay un error al procesar la solicitud, deberias depurar la api

Answer (score 0):

Los bloques using y Try-Catch están mal ordenados. Así como está, con el Try-Catch sólo estás contemplando la posibilidad que falle la ejecución del método .Find() en la línea var `reg = db.Cat_FormatoLiberados.Find(IdDocumento);`  y algunas subsiguientes.

Estructuralo así:

```
try
{
    using (var db = new ContratosEntities())
    {
        using (var tran = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var reg = db.Cat_FormatoLiberados.Find(IdDocumento);
            ..
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ..
}
```

De esa manera cualquier Exception arrojada será atrapada por el bloque Catch.